# Flexbox: how to optimise material design dashboard layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to build some reusable templates, ideally with elegant and minimalist flex-based CSS. This template is for a dashboard with five "cards" of different sizes. Cells 2,3,5 should be equal width, probably about a quarter width. Cells 1,4 should take the rest. **Edit:** height-wise, all cells apart from cell1 should be the same height as each other, i.e. less tall than cell 1. So the overall effect is one giant card, three mini cards, and one wide but low card.

https://jsfiddle.net/2jjuxdhw/8/

I thought align-content:stretch would mean the cells would fill the space vertically, but this isn't working. Also, do I really need all the sections styled as rows and columns? I wonder if there is a neater way of doing it. Thanks for any help.

HTML

```
<div id="container">


         <div class="column fullheight" id="column2">

        <section class="row row1">

          <div class="cell" id="cell1"><div>cell1</div></div>

          <section class="column">
            <div class="cell" id="cell2"><div>cell2</div></div>

            <div class="cell" id="cell3"><div>cell3</div></div>
          </section>

        </section>
        <section class="row row2">

          <div class="cell" id="cell4"><div>cell4</div></div>

          <div class="cell" id="cell5"><div>cell5</div></div>

        </section>


      </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   div#container {
      position: relative;
      height: 400px;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      align-items: stretch;
    }


 div#column2 {
      flex-grow:3;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
      /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
      align-content: stretch;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    div#column2 section.row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      /*align-content: stretch;*/
    }

    div#column2 section.column {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

    }

    section.column, div.cell { flex: 1 0 auto; }


    div.cell {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      padding: 0.5em;

    }

    div#cell1,div#cell4 { padding-left: 1em; flex: 3 0 auto; }
    div#cell1,div#cell2 { padding-top: 1em; }
    div#cell2,div#cell3, div#cell5 { padding-right: 1em; }

    div.cell > div {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2jjuxdhw/8/

Comment: Didn't read the entire thing, but since you're struggling with flexbox (as am I), I thought I'd leave this here for you, hoping it will help you, as it helped me: [flexyboxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/). Oh, also you should turn your CSS/HTML code into a runnable Stack Snippet, so it will be easier for people to reproduce your issue.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great resource for all things flexbox related. I am looking at your code right now and simplifying it. One thing I have noted is that there are a lot of display:flexbox; on "child" elements that do not need them. You have to understand that there are some flexbox properties that are meant to manipulate the parent and some are meant to manipulate the elements within the parent that has the display:flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

To answer your updated question, you could take an approach like this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysjagk7v/1/)

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row--top {
  flex: 2;
}

.row--bottom {
  flex: 1;
}

.cell-wrap {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  margin: .5em;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row--top">
    <div class="cell">cell one</div>
    <div class="cell-wrap">
      <div class="cell">cell two</div>
      <div class="cell">cell three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row--bottom">
    <div class="cell">cell four</div>
    <div class="cell-wrap">
      <div class="cell">cell five</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Original answer**

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do8bctxf/1/)

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  min-width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  margin: .5em;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="cell">cell one</div>
    <div class="cell">cell four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="cell">cell two</div>
    <div class="cell">cell three</div>
    <div class="cell">cell five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, and your code is very lean! But I want cells 4 and 5 to be the same height. So actually cells 2,3,4,5 are all the same height, while cell 4 is wide. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @emma Apologies, I misunderstood your question. What is wrong with your original solution then? If you could provide a pic of what you want the end result it might help, cheers

Comment: Mine just felt inelegant - compare it to your first answer! I wondered if there was a way without nesting elements. And also I couldn't get it to stretch vertically, which you have done. Thanks